# Detecting a Facebook user is an admin: app scoped ids

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since the introduction of Graph v2.0, apps are now granted app scoped ids instead of users' real profile ids. What this means is that if I run `FB.getLoginStatus`, the user id of the logged in user is now the app scoped id rather than the main one.

However, what if I want to work out if a user is an admin of my app? I need to use an app token, and query [app/roles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/roles). However, the id returned here in the admins section is the **actual** profile id of the user, not the app scoped id.

My question is - is it even possible to work out if a user is an admin of an app anymore?

Comment: Have the user authed your app? And app/roles still return actually user ids? If so file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: The user **has** authed the app - the app scoped id is coming in just fine. But app/roles still returns user ids, yes. A bug report sounds like a good idea.